# Backreference format in Winmerge regex

Tags: regex, winmerge

I'm trying to search-and-replace wit a regex in a file in Winmerge, however I can't find the right format for making a backreference.

For example I search `(\w+)`, and I tried to replace by `"$1"`, `"\1"`, `"\\1"`, `"${1}"`, but neither of those works.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: according to the documentation Winmerge uses PCRE. So the backreference format should be `\1`. However I don't have a Winmerge installation available for testing. Maybe you can try to use relative back reference `\g{-1}` (http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).
Can you maybe share your real pattern?

Comment: Unfortunately `\g{-1}`doesn't work either. Well my real pattern is almost what I posted, I want to add quotes around single word arguments, that is, replace `=(\w+)` by `="(\1)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winmerge does not support replacing with regex. You can only use regex as find filters, which are facilitated with PCRE.

Comment: what a pity! is this still the case?

Answer (score 2):

format is \1 and you need winmerge 2.15.2

https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/2172/